# How many function A to B satisfied from f(1)=x

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

What does it mean to satisfy a function A to B from $f(1)=x$ ? Where

$$ A=\{1,2,3,4\}\ \  \text{and}\ \  B=\{x,y,z\}$$

The answer should be $3^3$, but why?

Comment: Sorry about that in the problem it should me A={1,2,3,4} NOT!  {1,2,3,4,5}. But it is the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they are asking is for you to figure out how many functions from $A\to B$ send the input $1$ to the output $x.$

The idea, here, is that any function $A\to B$ will send each input--that is, each element of $A$--to a unique output--that is, a unique element of $B.$ Determining an output for each input uniquely determines such a function. There are $4$ inputs, and for each input there are $3$ possible outputs--so, for example, if we are building a function $g:A\to B,$ there are three different possible choices for $g(1),$ three different choices for $g(2),$ and so on. Thus, since we can assign any output to any input--meaning, for example, that our choice of $g(1)$ has no effect on what we can choose for $g(2),$ $g(3),$ and $g(4)$--then there are $3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3=3^4$ distinct functions $A\to B.$

For *your* problem, we are dealing with a restriction: we *must* have $f(1)=x.$ Hence, we only have flexibility in our choices of $f(2),f(3),$ and $f(4).$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: So since we must have $f(1)=x$, and we only have flexibility in $f(2),f(3),f(4),$ and $f(5)$. The $3^4$ that satisfies the function from A to B. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: For your originally posted (erroneous) set $A$, you're correct. See my edited post.

Comment: Okay, so if we take the next question where they ask to satisfy a function A to B from $f(1)=f(2)=x$, then we only have the flexibility to choices $f(3),$ and $f(4)$. Then this should be $3^2$. Is this right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this problem Cameron. If I want to learn more about this. What do I need to search for, which theme ?

Comment: Try googling "fundamental counting principle." That's basically what I was applying, here.